# how to stub a method that takes and argument

Tags: ruby, minitest

I'm kind of stuck (Maybe because this is my first time using Minitest) wherein I want to `stub` a method that takes an argument.

```
def self.bonsai_site_configuration(since=nil)
  data = []
  Site.all.reduce(data) do |data, site|
    begin
      data << JSON.parse(site.bonsai_desc)
    rescue StandardError => exception
      notify_exception(exception)
    end
   data
  end
 return {data: data`}
end
```

All I'm looking over here is that if test cases wherein if the `site.bonsai_desc` fails(i.e throw an exception). It should invoke `notify_exception` with given `exception`

Here how my minitest looks like

```
 test "should return bonsai_site_configuration even on exception" do
    site = Site.first
    raises_exception = -> { raise 'boom' }
    Site.stub(:all, [site]) do
      site.stub(:bonsai_desc, raises_exception) do
        Site.stub(:notify_exception) do
          bonsai_information = Site.bonsai_site_configuration
          assert_equal(0, bonsai_information[:data].count)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Upon running the minitest the test passes but I want to ensure that argument check is also included.

What am I suppose to do?

Comment: Saw https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-9/docs/argument-matchers/explicit-arguments?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Minitest